# C# How do I get out of this loop?

Tags: c#

How do I get out of this loop?

I wrote a program that checks to see if corresponding places in the numbers are the same total. The console output should be true or false. I wrote that, and then added the top part that interacts with the user, and now I get stuck in a loop. How do I get out of it?

```
using System;

namespace DeliverablePart1
{
    class DeliverablePart1
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string gameAnswer;
            bool repeat1 = true, repeat2 = true;

            while (repeat1 == true)

            {
                repeat2 = true;
                Console.WriteLine("Would you like to compare 2 numbers to see if their corresponding place is same total?");
                gameAnswer = Console.ReadLine();

                while (repeat2 == true)
                {
                    if (gameAnswer == "yes" || gameAnswer == "yes" || gameAnswer == "YES")
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Please enter a three digit whole number");
                        string firstValue = Console.ReadLine();
                        int firstNumber = ValidInteger(firstValue);

                        Console.WriteLine("Please enter a second three digit whole number");
                        string secondValue = Console.ReadLine();
                        int secondNumber = ValidInteger(secondValue);

                        repeat1 = false;
                        repeat2 = false;
                    }

                    else if (gameAnswer == "no" || gameAnswer == "No" || gameAnswer == "NO")
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Okay, exiting now");
                        repeat1 = false;
                        repeat2 = false;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("I do not understnad what you have said");
                        repeat2 = false;
                    }

                    void Add(int firstNumber, int secondNumber)
                    {
                        int length1 = firstNumber.ToString().Length;
                        int length2 = secondNumber.ToString().Length;

                        string userInput;

                        if (length1 == length2)
                        {
                            string Answer = Convert.ToString(Compare(firstNumber, secondNumber, length1));
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            userInput = "invalid user input - Check number of digits next time.";
                            Console.WriteLine(userInput);
                            Console.ReadKey();
                        }
                        Console.ReadKey();
                    }

                    int ValidInteger(string digit1)
                    {
                        int value = 0;
                        string notInt = "This is not an integer.";
                        {
                            bool successfullyParsed = int.TryParse(digit1, out value);
                            if (successfullyParsed)
                            {
                                int firstNumber = Convert.ToInt32(value);
                                return value;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                Console.WriteLine(notInt);
                                Console.ReadKey();
                                Environment.Exit(0);
                                return value;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    string Compare(int a, int b, int c)
                    {
                        int lastDigitA;
                        int lastDigitB;

                        lastDigitA = (a % 10);
                        lastDigitB = (b % 10);
                        int sumStatic = lastDigitA + lastDigitB;

                        do
                        {
                            lastDigitA = (a % 10);
                            lastDigitB = (b % 10);
                            a = a / 10;
                            b = b / 10;
                            c--;
                            int sumCompare = lastDigitA + lastDigitB;

                            if (sumCompare != sumStatic)
                            {
                                Console.WriteLine("False");
                                return "False";
                            }
                        }
                        while (c != 0);
                        Console.WriteLine("True");
                        return "True";
                    }

                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You have multiple loops here.  Which one is running indefinitely?  When you step through the code in a debugger, where do you expect the loop condition to change and why?

Comment: What is the value of `repeat1` when that happens @moguth ?

Comment: This code doesn't make any sense to me.  How are you defining methods in a method?  Why do you have a loop with no body at the end?

Comment: WTF list: `while (repeat2 == true)`, `if (gameAnswer == "yes" || gameAnswer == "yes" || gameAnswer == "YES")`, `int ValidInteger(string digit1)` ... I give up.

Comment: @moguth: `"nothing gets caught in the debugger. It processes through fine"` - Then what's the problem?  If, when you debug, the code "processes through just fine" then what are you asking?  None of us know what you're observing when you run this or what you expect it to do.  You have to be specific.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From my understanding, it looks like you want the user to enter in three ints (with some input validation), and put the three ints through the `Compare()` function. If the function returns true, then say "True" to the console, and if it's false then say "False" to the console. If that's the case, I refactored your code into this (and it doesn't get stuck in a loop):

```
using System;

namespace DeliverablePart1
{
    internal class DeliverablePart1
    {
        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Would you like to compare 2 numbers to see if their corresponding place is same total?");
            var shouldContinue = Console.ReadLine();

            if (shouldContinue != null && shouldContinue.Equals("yes", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))
            {
                var firstNum = GetIntFromUser("Please enter a three digit whole number");
                var secondNum = GetIntFromUser("Please enter a three digit whole number");
                var thirdNum = GetIntFromUser("Please enter a three digit whole number");

                Console.WriteLine(Compare(firstNum, secondNum, thirdNum) ? "True" : "False");
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Exiting");
            }

            // waits for the user to press a key to exit the app, so that they can see their result
            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Makes the user enter in a three digit number, and exits if they say "no"
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="msg">The message prompt to ask for the integer</param>
        /// <returns>System.Int32., or will exit</returns>
        public static int GetIntFromUser(string msg)
        {
            while (true)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(msg);
                var valFromUser = Console.ReadLine()?.Trim();

                if (valFromUser != null)
                {
                    int result;
                    if (int.TryParse(valFromUser.Trim(), out result) && valFromUser.Length == 3)
                    {
                        return result;
                    }
                    if (valFromUser.Equals("no", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Exiting.");
                        Environment.Exit(0);
                    }
                }
                Console.WriteLine("Hmm, that's not a three digit number. Try again.");
            }
        }

        public static bool Compare(int a, int b, int c)
        {
            var lastDigitA = a % 10;
            var lastDigitB = b % 10;
            var sumStatic = lastDigitA + lastDigitB;

            do
            {
                lastDigitA = a % 10;
                lastDigitB = b % 10;
                a = a / 10;
                b = b / 10;
                c--;
                var sumCompare = lastDigitA + lastDigitB;

                if (sumCompare != sumStatic)
                {
                    return false;
                }
            } while (c != 0);
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```